# Should this relationship be unidirectional or not?

Tags: core-data

I have a Transaction entity that has a unidirectional to-many relationship with a Product entity. I've made it unidirectional because I want a transaction to be associated with a product, but I don't want a product to be associated with any transactions.

I know Apple suggest that you should make relationships have inverses, but I don't think having an inverse relationship from Product to Transaction is appropriate here is it? I know I will have to manually set the deletion of the product from the Transaction if a Product is deleted, but that's fine.

Does it matter what the delete rule is for the unidirectional relationship, since it won't make any difference will it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the inverse, even if you aren't going to directly use it. There is a reason that [Apple suggests doing this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html):

> Core Data uses this information to ensure the consistency of the
>   object graph if a change is made (see “Manipulating Relationships and
>   Object Graph Integrity”).

The question I have for you is, why wouldn't you set the inverse? If you don't want the product to be associated with Transactions, then just don't access that relationship.

Comment: Won't the inverse relationship take up space in the Product database table though?

Comment: Not enough where it is worth risking graph integrity.

Comment: What should the deletion rule be set to on the inverse relationship from Product to Transaction in order to be able to access the name of the product even if the original product has been deleted?

Comment: If you want to do that you will have to keep you Product around, or at the very least, record the name of the Product in your Transaction product. Better to keep the Product around though. Instead of actually deleting it, add a "deleted" attribute of Boolean type. When you "delete" just flip the boolean. Your product will live on, but you can easily determine if it is alive or dead.